# Can't access public class enum in page_load ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, enums

I'm confused, I have the following class definition

```
public class User
{
    public enum UserRoleTypes : int
    {
        Guest = 0,
        User = 1,
        Administrator = 2,
        Developer = 3,
    }
}
```

However when trying to access this public enum in a Page_Load method like such.

```
public partial class Options_AccessControl : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        User currentUser = OCMSession.getCurrentUser(this);
        if (currentUser.getRoleID() < (int)User.UserRoleTypes.Administrator)
        {
            LogWriter logger = new LogWriter();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error.

```
Error   5   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'UserRoleTypes' and no extension method 'UserRoleTypes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) H:\SVN\OCM\Options\AccessControl.aspx.cs    15  49  OCM
```

However the same code works without the User class definition. Like Entity.UserRoleTypes or if I move the enum definition outside of the class. Any help understanding this error is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using User, but in this context that's a property of the Page. It's of type IPrincipal and doesn't contain your enum. If you want to use your newly created class, you have to be more specific or choose a different name for your class.

Comment: Is there a way to specify that class over the page property? Maybe placing it into a namespace.

Comment: @garyamorris, yes, simply specify the more specific path to it using the namespace... it's ugly in my opinion, but it works.